# jQuery Page Load According to Location Pathname

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pathname

I'm currently having trouble trying to load a page according to a header through jQuery!
Initially when I load a page through .click, I change the header to `#/Pathname`. Now where my problem comes is, rather than individuals having to constantly go to the main page and then click a button where it leads to that `pathname`
I want them to be able to go directly to `www.example.com/main.php#/Pathname` and have jQuery be able to load the page... would that be possible?
I tried this code, but no luck:

```
if (document.location.pathname == "main.php#/Home") {
            $('#content').load('home.php', function( response, status, xhr ) {
          if ( status == "error" ) {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
            $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
          }
          });
}
```

Ignore the error script it's just there for my own purposes!

Comment: When you say 'no luck', what exactly is the issue? Have you used the browser console to validate `document.location.pathname` is returning the expected value? Right now when you click one of these buttons, does anything happen, be it displaying your error and/or logging any JS errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to manage "state" of page.

I highly recommand you to have a look on **window.history.pushState** that helps you rewrite properly the URI of your page but also manage proper History sessions.

To push a state :

```
window.history.pushState("","",URI );
```

to popState

window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {

```
your code here to manage event history
```

});

Moreover, you are also having trouble PARSING your URI.
I use that function for uri parsing and checking as my pages are with parameters such as ?id=...&name=

```
function getUrlParameter( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return null;
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

So in your case, I'd :

```
window.history.pushState("","",URI + "?page=home);
```

and to test if on location I have home : => `getUrlParameter("home")`

**Is your formating of page with #/ mandatory ?**
If not, use the kind of code I quote that will enable you to manage proper history, goback and more.

If yes, we will think about another solution.

If this not completly answers to your question, then please provide more info an what this is not replying.
GoodLuck

--- EDIT

```
function getUrlParameter( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\#/]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return null;
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

Comment: Yes the '#/' is mandatory because the links that are pressed to load a page have a href of "#/Pathname". When I change the href to "?page=pathname" the jquery no longer works and it loads an error.

Comment: I have changed the regexS to check for pattern #/

Therefore, if your launch getUrLParameter(pathname) will respond with true

Comment: Okay I'm sorry if I sound stupid for asking this but I don't know javascript at all, and so how would I launch that jquery script if the pathlocation is valid

Comment: try to learn JS a bit. Nothing is magic.
JQUERY is just a Javascript librairy.. so if you don't know the basics, none can help you